# How to auto-update a sideload UWP app without first installing with .appinstaller file

Tags: uwp, appinstaller

I have a UWP app that is distributed via sideload (not through the Store) for various reasons. This app has auto-updating enabled, and thus has a .appinstaller file (and associated app packages and dependencies) hosted on the web. If I install via the `ms-appinstaller` protocol, or by downloading and running the .appinstaller file, automatic updates work fine.

However, installing via the .appx does not allow the app to automatically update. This is a scenario because there are cases where I need to provision the app (via `Add-AppxProvisionedPackage`) so that it installs for any new users on a given device. Since `Add-AppxProvisionedPackage` doesn't seem to support .appinstaller files, and it doesn't seem like installing from the .appx package itself allows for auto-updating, how am I able to provision an app and still allow it to auto-update?

A related question is: What causes an app to check with some appinstaller file on the web for updates? Is that something that is baked into the app? Something written to the registry? Where does the information live that causes an app to check for updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, installing via the .appx does not allow the app to automatically update.

This is expected. The auto-update functionality is available only when you install the application using the `.appinstaller` file, not when installing the APPX or MSIX directly.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/app-installer-file-overview?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077):

"*You *must* share with your users the App Installer file, instead of the actual app container...*"

> Where does the information live that causes an app to check for updates?

In the installed package. There are some [APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/app-installer-documentation?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) available to retrieve information about apps with an App Installer association.

Comment: Thanks. So to clarify, there is no way to auto-update a provisioned app (have an app auto-install for a user and then auto-update), right? I was hoping there would be some bits in the produced appx that would associate it, but I guess that happens through the .appinstaller doing the installation.